# Как настроить Jenkins, чтобы он автоматом вводил пароль от репозитория при работе через гит?

Tags: git, jenkins

Есть настроенный Jenkins на сервере, его задача забирать с мастера репозитория обновления на разные поддомены, то есть прописаны команды типа: `git pull origin master`. Связь с репозиторием настроена через ssh ключ с паролем. При запуске данных команд мне приходится каждый раз вводить пароль, может ли это делать автоматом Дженкинс ?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

Answer (score 1):

насколько мне известно, «ввести» что-нибудь по запросу от какого-нибудь из процессов, запускаемых во время выполнения задания, jenkins не умеет.

для взаимодействия с серверами по протоколу *git* (поверх протоколов *ssh* или *http*) предназначен [специальный plugin с одноимённым названием](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

пример использования в [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/):

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage (...) {
      steps {
        git url: "url хранилища", credentialsId: "идентификатор"
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

здесь `идентификатор` — это идентификатор от [*credentials*](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) типа «ssh username with private key» (ключ, конечно, может быть зашифрован паролем, но этот пароль будет храниться рядом с ключом, так что смысл в шифровании отсутствует).

---

если вы не используете *pipeline* или *plugin git*, можно воспользоваться [*plugin*-ом *ssh agent*](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin). в конфигурации задания надо будет отметить соответствующий пункт (*ssh agent*) и выбрать нужные *credentials* (того же типа, что упомянут выше). тогда в начале выполнения задания будет запущен процесс *ssh-agent* и все запускаемые в рамках задания процессы будут его потомками. что позволит программе *ssh* (к которой обратится программа *git*) аутентифицироваться с теми самыми выбранными вами *credentials*.